# adding sfml on qt creator 5.11

Tags: c++, qt, audio, cmake, sfml

[image: main]

I actually work with qt creator 5.11.0, I have already add `sfml` to Qt Creator following this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWvD4mUpyfU&t=1784s), it perfectly works but when I try to use audio library by creating an instance of `SoundBuffer`, after running, `the process was ended forcefully` display on command lines.

After debugging, I have:

```
exception at 0x7775d4f2, code 0xc0000135:DLL not found ,flags 0*0.....".
```

Please help me to debug this. Thanks.

Comment: "DLL not found" - you need to ensure the DLL is somewhere it can be found.  Either in the same directory as the executable, or on the PATH.

Comment: already done it but problem persist,

Comment: i did samething like the video

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to watch a crappy video (which could be replaced by a page of plain text and *possibly* a couple of screen shots), If you want more help, you're going to need to post a [mcve]

Comment: on the main picture i have put soundBuffer on comment and after executing, apps go on well, but when i instantiate, its crashed,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect a code in the question post **as text**, so it can be copy-pasted and searched for a specific constructs. Please, edit your question and replace the code *image* with the code itself.